# How does Link Aggregation actually increases bandwidth?

Tags: switch, ieee-802.1ax, lag

For example, if we need 450 Mbps of bandwidth to transmit data and have only a 100-Mbps Fast Ethernet ports, we can create a LAG bundle containing five 100-Mbps Fast Ethernet ports. But I also read that data at any point of time will flow only through one of the physical ports, meaning the data will not flow parallelly through all the ports ( which can cause out of delivery issues ), so how does LAG actually increase the bandwidth and speed?

Comment: There a multiple questions here that answer your question. Start with the one in the link above, then search for others.

Comment: ok thank you. But can you explain this- All the packets belonging to any individual session should go down the same single link. So how does having multiple links help in this case if all the packets have to go through one link only?

Comment: Because you have multiple flows, not just one flow. It does not help just one flow, but that flow may be able to use more bandwidth of the link because other flows that would use part of the bandwidth may use other links. It depends on the hashing algorithm as to which link a flow uses. In aggregate, you get more bandwidth, just not for a single flow. Spreading a single flow across multiple links will cause other problems, and can slow or kill a particular application.